# Append to array inside a Firebase Closure in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to append to an array inside a Firebase closure,
I declared the array outside of the closure `var CanJoinArray = [String]()` But when I try to append to the array inside the closure: `self.CanJoinArray.append("hello")` and print it outside of the closure, `print (CanJoinArray)` it doesn't print. However, when I print the array inside the (inside) closure, it is able to append and print. How can I solve this? Thanks!

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (FIRDataSnap) in
        for child in FIRDataSnap.children.allObjects {
            let key = (child as AnyObject).key as String
            self.myArray.append(key)
        }

        for (_, element) in self.myArray.enumerated() {
            self.ref.child(element).child("Players").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (Snap) in
                if Snap.childrenCount < 2 {
                    self.CanJoinArray.append("hello")
                }
                else {
                    print("Can't join lobby\(element)... Full!")
                }
                print(CanJoinArray) //this does work
            })
        }
       print (CanJoinArray) //this doesn't work
    })
}
```

The database Structure:

```
{
 "Lobbies" : {
    "RANDOMUUID" : {
       "LobbyName" : {
          "LobbyName" : ""
       },
       "Players" : {
          "user1" : "USERUID#"
       }
    }
 },
 "Users" : {
    "USERUID#" : {
      "DisplayName" : "user1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean 'if' statement? Not sure what an 'in' statement is.

Comment: yes sorry...   I meant an if statement

Comment: Please post a short sample of your code showing the problem

Comment: @simonWasHere Just did that.

Comment: What is the connection between myArray and CanJoinArray?

Comment: myArray is all of the children in the database and then I use another observe single event to go into each of the children and go into their child called players and in there check if there are more then 2 children

Comment: This isn't going to work (mostly). Your trying to load data that's being pulled from the internet in a tight loop into an array, and then print the array. More than likely the print statement will happen before the array is populated with data from the internet so it will be an empty array.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your Firebase structure (as TEXT please, NO images) so we can take a look? You may want to consider an alternative structure to make this easier.

Comment: Oh, and the issue has nothing to do with the *if* statement - it has everything to do with the 'inside' Firebase closure. The question has been clarified for readability - check it over.

Comment: @Jay I posted my structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of directions you can go...

It appears that you want to maintain a list of lobbies that are available, and the availability is determined by the number of players in the lobby. In this case 0 or 1 players means it's available and if 2 or more means it's full.

The first option that comes to mind is to change your structure by adding a is_available node within the lobby. When a player joins that lobby, add their uid to the players child and update the is_available to false if it's the second player. The structure would look something like this:

```
Lobbies
  lobby_id_0
    lobby_name: "lobby 5"
    is_available: false
    players
      uid_0: true
      uid_1: true
  lobby_id_1
    lobby_name: "lobby 12"
    is_available: true
    players
      uid_2: true
  lobby_id_2
    lobby_name: "some lobby"
    is_available: false
    players
      uid_3: true
      uid_4: true
```

The code would be a query:

```
let lobbiesRef = rootRef.child("Lobbies")
let queryRef = lobbiesRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "is_available").queryEqual(toValue: true)
queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    for child in snapshot.children {
       let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
       let lobbyDict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
       let lobbyKey = snap.key
       self.availableLobbyArray.append(lobbyKey)
    }
})
```

This would add lobby_id_1 to the array as the other two lobbies each have two players.

A second solution is to keep second node that lists lobbies that are available.

Here's the All_Lobbies node and the Available_Lobbies node

```
All_Lobbies
   lobby_id_0
     lobby_name: "lobby 5"
     players
         uid_0: true
         uid_1: true
   lobby_id_1
     lobby_name: "lobby 12"
     players
        uid_2: true

Available_Lobbies
   lobby_id_1: true
```

Kind of the same concept; when a player joins lobby_id_1 and it's two players (so it's full), simply remove that lobby from the Available_Lobbies node.

The code to see which are available:

```
let availableLobbiesRef = rootRef.child("Available_Lobbies")
availableLobbiesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    for child in snapshot.children {
       let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
       let lobbyKey = snap.key
       self.availableLobbyArray.append(lobbyKey)
    }
})
```

The advantage of this structure is two-fold. We eliminate the query completely because only available lobbies are stored in that node. Queries are much 'heavier' than an observe and take more resources. The second thing is that if there are 1 Million Available_Lobbies, we are loading in far less data!

Comment: Everything works, the only small problem is: i get this Warning     `Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "is_available" at /Lobbies to your security rules for better performance`

Comment: @adameliezerov Indexing  your data can significantly improve query performance - but you have to plan ahead on what kind of queries you'll be using. Read over [Index Your Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) for some really good examples and use cases. If you are just testing or getting started you can ignore that message but when you start using the app or working with larger data sets it becomes much more important.

Comment: Ok. Another problem: whenever I create a new lobby I also do this: `self.ref.child("Available_Lobbies").setValue([self.uuid: true])` but then, every time I create a new lobby, it rewrites the old one.

Comment: @adameliezerov Right. It's doing exactly what you are telling it do to: write to the node *rootref/Available_Lobbies/uid: true*. So this code isn't creating a new lobby, it's writing to a specific lobby. If you want to create new lobbies, you should be using .childByAutoId to create the lobby keys (lobby_0, lobby_1 etc in my answer). .childByAutoId generates a unique key when called which is perfect for node keys. It's really a separate question if you are still having issues. There are a *lot* of references and examples available here.

Comment: Then how do I get that autoId?

Comment: @adameliezerov It's laid out in the documentation [Read and Write Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

Comment: Is it possible I can get your skype to ask a couple of more questions? Thanks.

Comment: @adameliezerov That's what this form is for - sharing information! Craft some code, create a Firebase structure and post a good question when you get stuck or need direction!

Answer (score 0):

Just move the print statement up one maybe,

```
 for (_, element) in self.myArray.enumerated() {

        self.ref.child(element).child("Players").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (Snap) in

            if Snap.childrenCount < 2 {
                self.CanJoinArray.append("hello")

            }
            else {
                print("Can't join lobby\(element)... Full!")

            }


        })

      print (CanJoinArray)

    }

  you were here

})
```

Comment: doesn't work. It still doesn't show anything was added to the array

Comment: What about moving it outside the completion below your original code?

Comment: It's empty if I do that.

Comment: You're on the right track here. Move the `print(CanJoinArray)` statement into the callback (two more lines up) and it'll work.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it prints the CanJoinArray the number of times that I have elements in MyArray

Comment: That is the expected behavior. If you want to wait until all items are loaded, you'll have to keep a counter. Since the loading happens asynchronously, you can't just depend on the order of the statements in your code.

Comment: How shall I go about doing that?