# Swift append array value not showing outside statement

Tags: arrays, swift

My scenario from my get call I received values and I appended with `var nameData = [String]()` array. nameData array values not showing outside statement. Please check my below code

```
// Global Declarions
var nameData = [String]()

// GET Call values append
 if let content = result["contacts"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
            for category in content {

                self.nameData.append(category["name"] as! String)
            }
            print(self.nameData) // here I am getting
        }
    }
   self.addDropDown()
   print(self.nameData) // Empty array showing
```

Now, My dropdown code below, Here I want to assign `nameData` array

```
func addDropDown(){

   print(self.nameData) // Empty array showing why???

        // For Top textField
        let dropDownTop = VPAutoComplete()
        dropDownTop.dataSource =  self.nameData           -->// Here I need to assign nameData values if i do its showing empty values.
        dropDownTop.onTextField = emailTF
        dropDownTop.onView = self.view
        dropDownTop.show { (str, index) in
            print("string : \(str) and Index : \(index)")
            self.emailTF.text = str
        }
}
```

Comment: How about `dropDownTop.dataSource = self.nameData`

Comment: within addDropDown function I am getting empty array @ Carpsen90. But inside for category in content {
                    self.nameData.append(category["name"] as! String)
                }  I can get.

Comment: How are you filling `nameData`?  And when are you executing `self.nameData.append(category["name"] as! String)`?

Comment: I updated my question please check once, Please. Once I received response from GET call I am graphing the name values and appending.The problem is outside loop I can't able to get append values. Showing array empty. @ Carpsen90

Comment: Could you please : `print(self.nameData)` just before `dropDownTop.dataSource = ...` and mention the result in your question

Comment: I updated @ Carpsen90 same issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486321/append-to-array-inside-a-firebase-closure-in-swift-3

Comment: Have you left out some import code here? Perhaps your `for` loop is actually inside some async completion handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if let content = result["contacts"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
        for category in content {
            self.nameData.append(category["name"] as! String)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.addDropDown() } 
    }
}
```

Add the drop down just after you fill the `nameData` array.

Comment: wow its working but some other issues came. Could you please tell me how can i store this values into Userdefault and show it dropdown?? @Carpsen90

Comment: [Here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults) are a few examples

Comment: great dude. I found one more solution for other issues...DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.addDropDown()
                } .....Thank you @ Carpsen90

Comment: Glad I could help @testapp